# How to add animation to changing fragments using Navigation Component?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

How to add animation to changing fragments using Navigation Architecture Component?

Comment: It is said in document if you just read it. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the Navigation Component documentation(https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) in the section: **Create a transition between destinations** (it's near the end of the document) you have it explained in detail.

You can either add them using the editor by selecting the arrow of the desired transition and then selecting the animations in the *Animations* section of the *Attributes* tab.

Or by referencing the animations in the xml file like in the example:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/specifyAmountFragment"
    android:name="com.example.buybuddy.buybuddy.SpecifyAmountFragment"
    android:label="fragment_specify_amount"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_specify_amount">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/confirmationAction"
        app:destination="@id/confirmationFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
 </fragment>
```

You can use regular anim resources for this animations

Comment: hmm. But seems like NavOption doesn't allow us to specify the animation duration. All we can do is set the duration in every anim file.

Comment: is there a way to do Circular Reveal transition with it

Answer (score 15):

If you want to add animation through programmatically, use **NavOptions** [(here)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavOptions).

```
NavOptions.Builder navBuilder =  new NavOptions.Builder();
navBuilder.setEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_left).setExitAnim(R.anim.slide_right).setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_left).setPopExitAnim(R.anim.slide_right);

//Inside Activity
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
navController.navigate(R.id.destinationFragmentId,null,navBuilder.build());
//Inside Fragment
NavHostFragment.findNavController(YoutFragment.this)
                            .navigate(R.id.destinationFragmentId, null, navBuilder.build());
```